# Django - Fetching data works on Shell but returns " object is not iterable" on debug

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to fetch data from different tables with ForeignKeys.

I have a model Clients and other Trip. Trip has a ForeignKey to Clients. I wanna fetch the Trips to each Client, and output on an HTML page.

When I run `ls = Clients.objects.get(nif=123123123)` and then `ts = Trip.objects.filter(client = ls)` I am able to retrieve the data I want from the Trip model.

But when I try doing so on django, I get a `Exception Value: 'Clients' object is not iterable`.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Primeiro Nome")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Apelido")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Morada")
    nif = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], primary_key=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])


class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name="Ref. Viagem")
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Cliente")
    out_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, related_name="outbound_flight" ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Ida")
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Hotel")
    in_flight = models.ForeignKey (Flight, related_name="inbound_flight", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Regresso")
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Clients, Hotels, Trip

def client(request, nif):
    ls= Clients.objects.get(nif=nif)
    ts= Trip.objects.filter(client = ls)
    context = {'ls': ls, 'ts' : ts}
    return render(request, "backend/client.html", context)
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.backend, name="backend"),
    path("cliente/<int:nif>", views.client, name="client"),
    path("hotel/<int:id>", views.hotel, name="hotel"),
]
```

And then my `client.html`:

```
   {% for ls in ls %} 

    ...


    <div class="field">
                    <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Morada" value="{{ls.address}}" readonly>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left">
                        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Morada" value="{{ls.mobile}}" readonly>
                        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ls.nif}}" readonly>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        <i class="far fa-id-card"></i>
                    </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                {% for ts in ts %}
                <div class="field">
                    <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ts.trip_id}}" readonly>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        <i class="far fa-id-card"></i>
                    </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
 {% endfor %}
...
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: which part is throwing the error? you didn't state it.

Comment: you may wanna use a debugger to see what is happening there

Comment: @Mox, when i try accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/cliente/nifHERE` is where I get the error. And it highlights `{% for ls in ls %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls = Clients.objects.get()` returns one object, not a list/queryset.

So `{% for ls in ls %}` is not possible because you have just one object.

`ls` is a `Clients` object and the error is telling you can't iterate over a `Clients` object.

Remove that loop.

[On a side note: `{% for ts in ts %}` is bad coding practice. You're overriding the `ts` name and it's not even clear what the object is. Rename to `{% for trip in ts %}` or even better rename `ts` to `trips` as well.]

Comment: Oh, wow that was a great indication. Ok, I changed `ls` to `ts` and now it fetches the fetches data. But, because there are two Trip entries associated to that Clients, it duplicates every single field. Any suggestion on how to address this!

Comment: I said remove the first loop entirely (delete it, not replace it with something else). It sounds like you now have two `ts` loops inside each other.

Comment: I removed the second `ts` loop. I only have a `ts` loop at the top of the page.

Comment: You should have done the opposite, only loop for the fields specific to `ts`.